# Acer Aspire Z5101 Realtek Network Card Not connecting after resuming from suspend mode

Tags: wireless, suspend, acer, realtek, aspire

I have a problem with my realtek network card not connecting after resuming from suspend mode.

Ubuntu 13.10 Realtek network card using the `r8712u` driver on an Acer Aspire all in one z5101, any help appreciated.

This is the fix for this Machine
Here is a technique that sometimes works:

gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
Add a single line:

SUSPEND_MODULES="r8712u"
Proofread, save and close gedit. Reboot, suspend and let us have your report.

for me the driver is r8712u.
You find the driver by sudo lshw -C network

the line driver = 'the driver', the driver is what you use in that line

SUSPEND_MODULES="the driver"